# Storing Json in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage, getjson

I would like to store search results as cache in localStorage.

I would like to store all the cache as one localStorage value:

```
localStorage.getItem('search-cache')
```

Inside it I would like to have JSON object which I can add properties and retreive them.
Unfortunately it doesn't work and the localStorage is not updated with the json results (its value keep being `'{}'`).

I am not a javascript proffesional so please guide me how to do it well.

Here is the current code to cache results:

```
    var query = $(this).val();

    var cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('search-cache'));

    if (cache == null) {
        cache = '[{}]';
    }

    if (cache[query] == null) {

        $.getJSON('/api/guides/search?query=' + query, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, guide) {
                $('#results').append('<li class="result-item">' + guide.Name + '</li>');
            });

            cache[query] = data;
            localStorage.setItem('search-cache', JSON.stringify(cache));
        });
    }
    else {
        $.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('search-cache')[query]), function (index, guide) {
            $('#results').append('<li class="result-item">' + guide.Name + '</li>');
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some holes in your logic.

```
var cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("..."));
if (cache == null) { cache = "[{}]"; }
```

Well, if the item DID exist, you've set cache to be equal to that object.
Otherwise, you've set cache to be equal to the string `"[{}]"`.

Instead of thinking about how you're going to build your localstorage, think about how you're going to build your result list.

```
var cache_json = localStorage.getItem("search-cache"),
    search_cache = JSON.parse(cache_json) || {};

var query = $("...").value(); // or whatever

search_cache[query] = search_cache[query] || { results : [] };

var list = $(......)
list.each(function () {
    search_cache[query].results.push( /* whatever you want in your array */ );
});


cache_json = JSON.stringify(search_cache);
localStorage.setItem("search-cache", query_json);
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work!

Furthermore, I learned other things from your answer - both syntax and javascript attitude.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in case of your item `search-cache` is not defined, the initialization of your cache variable is not right.

You should initialize your array like this :

```
if (cache == null) {
    cache = []; 
    cache[query] = null;
}
```

To meet the condition when testing

```
if (cache[query] == null)
```

however, you need to test it like this :

```
if(typeof cache[query] == 'undefined')
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I learned from it but it didn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

cache is an object and not an array, initialize like cache = {}
Rest of the code seems correct.